# value cannot be null: _context.Add(models.Reservations.FirstOrDefault());

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm getting the error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Here is the code for my action where I'm getting the error from:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.Models models)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(models.Reservations.FirstOrDefault());
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(models);
    }
```

Here is my models class:

```
public class Models
{
    public IEnumerable<ReservationsModel> Reservations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RoomsModel> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

This is an example of how I get the values from the View:

```
<select asp-for="Reservations.FirstOrDefault().RoomId" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Rooms)
        {
            <option asp-for="Reservations.FirstOrDefault().RoomId" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomID)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomID)</option>
        }
</select>
```

And finally my GET method in case you need it:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var obj = new Models.Models
    {
        Reservations = await _context.Reservations.ToListAsync(),
        Rooms = await _context.Rooms.ToListAsync()
    };
    return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: you have a lot of issues, from the original error (caused by how you write the code in the razor view) to how you design your models. I'm pretty sure that no one can help with such serious flaws (requiring a lot of adjustment), you'll probably being stuck or end up trying to solve it by yourself, especially with some in-person help from others (your friends, colleges ...).

Comment: Nobody helped other than this forum! I'm not sure if there are a lot of issues, because everything runs fine other than the create action on post. It was working fine before I implemented the 2 models class (it was working with 1 model). After adding it I made everything running other than the model that was working.

Comment: Can anyone explain my issues in the code. If my main logic is wrong here, would you just tell me what is the correct way to get data from one model and load data from another one(in the same View and Controller).

Comment: Hi can I have your reservationmodel, rooms model details. It looks like you are heading to wrong direction base on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the isse by myself! It was really simple!!!
Just created another property in the Models class of the same type, but instead of IEnumerable it was just of type ReservationsModel:

```
public class Models
{
    public IEnumerable<ReservationsModel> Reservations { get; set; }
    public ReservationsModel Reservations2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RoomsModel> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

and used it to pass the data from the View to the Controller.
Thanks to anyone that responded to my question!